# Perform string to date manipulation inside SSIS package with logical operators

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis

There are 2 string columns on an inbound file, both formatted YYYYMMDD.

If column 1 is after 10/1/2015, add 90 days to the column 1 date and load in column 2.  The data needs to be loaded in the system as YYYYMMDD string (so convert it back).

I'm trying to set up a Dervied Column module to do this, but I haven't been having much luck.

Here's what I have so far:

`[Column 1] >= (DT_DATE)"2015-10-01" ? DATEADD("dd",90,[Column 1])`

Please help.

Comment: Is it "on or after 10/1/2015" or just "after 10/1/2015". Why did you use the >= instead of just >

Comment: no much luck? please be more specific. If you're getting an error post it. If you're getting an unexpected output, post it. I can tell you if `[Column 1]` is a string not a date, then you can't use `DATEADD` on it and you also can't compare it to a date. When you are having issues you need to break it into pieces. Break your expression up into pieces. For example add a derived column which only has `DATEADD("dd",90,[Column 1])` in it. Does it work? If not just troubleshoot that piece until you get it right.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a simpler way of doing this, but since you are trying to do this with a derived column transform, this is how I did it for now.

1. Use a derived column transform to Convert column1 to date
2. Use a derived column transform to check condition and change value
3. Use a derived column transform to change it back to string

This is the code to change the YYYYMMDD string to date (I named it Column1AsDate)

```
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING(column1, 1, 4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(column1, 5, 2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(column1, 7, 2))
```

This is the code to check the condition (Now use Column1AsDate from the earlier transfor, I named this column as Column1AfterCondition)

```
Column1AsDate >= (DT_DATE)"2015-10-01" ? DATEADD("dd", 90, Column1AsDate) : Column1AsDate
```

This is the code to put it back to string (Using Column1AfterCondition from earlier transform)

```
(DT_WSTR, 4)DATEPART("yy", Column1AfterCondition) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART("mm", Column1AfterCondition), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)DATEPART("dd", Column1AfterCondition), 2)
```

Create a sample text file

[image: Sample file]

This is the package

[image: Package]

This is the data viewer after condition is checked

[image: Data Viewer after condition]

This is the data viewer after converting it back to string

[image: Data Viewer at the end]

So I suppose at the end, you can map the appropriate column to the destination. In this case the "Column1As String". Now that I think of it, I should have probably used better names.. but hopefully you get the picture.